# Designing application tier - what is your best practice?

Tags: java, architecture

Designing application tier is not trivial. At the end of the day, in every project we write (huge) number of so-called *business* methods (sometimes called *service* methods, although it is not related to services as in public APIs) that perform some business logic and usually do some database/storage operations (via storage tier). But designing/organizing/naming your application methods is not trivial as it sounds; people often have rules on project how application classes and methods should be designed. I am looking for pragmatic set of such rules for designing the application tier, so here are some questions:

1. Grouping methods in classes: by return type or?

   For example, method that updates a user belongs to class eg `UserService`. Or method that finds a user by some criteria belongs to the same class. But what happens when some method works on several types, like e.g. `registerUserForCompetition()`? Should this be in `UserService` or `CompetitionService`? The same question for the method `findUserCompetition()` - where would you put it?

   I often see a rule that says that this depends on methods return type. In our example, if method returns `User` (or collection of users etc) it should belong to `UserService`.
2. Method parameters: simple types (primitives, String...) or entities (e.g. `User`, `Competition`, `Registration`...)?

   This question is often asked, and people usually (statistically:) choose the first approach, using simple types as service arguments. But what to do when one such method calls the other method on the same resource? Let me give you an example: `registerUser(userId, competitionId)` may internally call `checkCompetition(competitionId)`. Both methods fetch the `Competition` from the storage. Obviously, this is done twice and, since we already have the `Competition` object we can use it to `checkCompetition` with it. So should we add overloaded method, or we should ignore this and just really on caching mechanism to prevent double fetching?

   On the other hand, having full types as parameters can not be universal rule, as many times the full information is not needed and there is no reason to fetch the full object while you need just it's id, that you already may have it.
3. Naming methods: how verbose methods name should be?

   Especially for finder methods. Should we have eg:

   - `findCompetition(userId, year)` or
   - `findCompetitionWithVenue(userId, year)` (since every `Competition` object has linked `Venue`); or
   - `findCompetitionForUserAndYear(userId, year)` or
   - `findCompetitionByUserIdAndYear(userId, year)` or just
   - `findUserCompetitionForYear(userId, year)`?

   When number of different criteria rises, it is easy to make a mess with finder method names, and I often see rules like this: `find<return-type>By<names-of-parameters>` or similar.
4. Do you have naming convention for application classes?

   Do your classes names end with `Service`? Do you separate *managers* from *services*, where manager deals with entities and services accept only simple types? Do you group all your business classes in the same package, or group them together with other related classes (model, controller...), based on functionality?

Please share your experience with focus on being pragmatic - for me it means that new developer can easily figure where to find business methods and how to write new ones, so everyone gets more productive. Also, if you have established rules, please share how your team is managed to follow them.

Comment: This question is conceptual and belongs on programmers.stackexchange.com. Once migrated, it will be an excellent question there.

Comment: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/233743/designing-service-methods-what-is-your-best-practice

Answer (score 1):

1. group services by functionality. in the same package should be also controler, part of model etc. there are better approaches then layered architecture. try DDD. it perfectly isolates functionality, makes it easier to find and change
2. usually it's good to have entities (model) hidden from the client and communicate with controllers through DTOs and ValueObjects. just in case you want to change your model in the future
3. they must be meaningful for your domain and consistent. and don't be affraid to refactor if your team says they are not clear. personally i would go with `findCompetition(user, year)` with non-primitive types because you can use method overloading but then in invocations you have to use constants or reading enablers like `findCompetition(forUserId(userId), forYear(year))` to explicitly tell the reader which version you are invoking.
4. what is manager? it means nothing. similarly to helper, handler etc. Service contains the logic that converts DTO to entities and the logic can't be pushed to the domain/entity because the logic operates on many entities. as stated before i group components (not only services) by functionality and therefore i add the 'Service' suffix because it helps me quickly find the logic in specific package (which contains model, controller, service, repository etc)

Comment: Do you know for any open-source DDD java project (of some product, if possible)? The net is full of rather simple DDD examples, and I feel I am not getting the complete picture.

Comment: no, i don't have any useful links. i agree, there are rather very simple projects in the net. i had the same problem